# Displaying search results dynamically as use interacts with controls

Tags: mysql, database, search, dynamic

I have a website and want to display search results dynamically meaning that as the user interacts with controls and selects options, the search results are populated in realtime - i.e. the user doesnt need to click the search button.

The data is stored in a MySQL relational data base.

Now I know this is likely to lead to a large server load for a user-set above a certain size - are there anyways to mitigate this?

Max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to mitigate the server load would be to introduce a slight timer delay before posting back to the server after each control is populated.  If you give the user 3 seconds or so to input an additional field, the user may have time to add a search parameter.  That could eliminate an extraneous query or two.

Answer (score 0):

Also I always like to set a max numbers of results returned.